# Azure Web Job Template missing .Net Core Target

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, webjob

In Visual Studio 2019 the Azure Web Job Template does not have any target option for .Net Core.
I need to have multiple Web Jobs within a single Web App(which will also do some other tasks)
Do i need to start as a .Net core console application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Job Template option is not available in web projects (.Net Core web app).
To enable web jobs you need to create your Web Jobs as a .NET Framework console app (.Net Core Console App).

[image]

Check [Console App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs) for further information.